# My Android app is getting crashed while executing the program

Tags: java, android

While executing the program my program is getting crashed.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;



public class MainLandingPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String filename = "MySampleFile.txt";
    private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
    File myInternalFile;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void AddLead(View view) {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads ", null);
        int n=curCSV.getCount();
        if (n >= 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "No Field has been declared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void SendCsv(View view) {
            sendEmail();
    }

    public void DeleteRecord(View view) {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads where id <> 1", null);
        int n = curCSV.getCount();
        if (n > 1) {
            deleteRecordALL();
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "Leads Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "No Leads to be Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void sendEmail() {


        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myInternalFile = new File(directory , filename);

        try {

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads ", null);

            while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {

                String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1)};
                Log.e("firstsql",arrStr[1]);
                Log.e("firstsql1",arrStr[0]);
                myOutWriter.append(arrStr[1]);
                myOutWriter.append("\n");
            }
            myOutWriter.close();
            curCSV.close();
            Log.e("Main", String.valueOf(myInternalFile.length()));

        } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
        }
        String[] TO = {""};
        String[] CC = {""};
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Lead created as of " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myInternalFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e("ppppp", myInternalFile.getName());
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.renu.customlead", directory);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.renu.customlead/files/MySampleFile.txt");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
            BufferedReader br =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myData = myData + "\n" + strLine;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myData);

        try {

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Sending mail Done "),1);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished sending email", "email xxxx");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="external_files" path="app_MyFileStorage/" />
</paths>
```

Android Manifest:

```
.........
  </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.renu.customlead"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
..........
```

My error code is showing:

```
03-08 01:45:55.705 7479-7479/com.example.renu.customlead E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.renu.customlead, PID: 7479
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.renu.customlead/app_MyFileStorage
   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
   at com.example.renu.customlead.MainLandingPage.sendEmail(MainLandingPage.java:185)
   at com.example.renu.customlead.MainLandingPage.SendCsv(MainLandingPage.java:61)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Well, probably error during sending of file. When does it happen? Start by commenting out email stuff and continue this way

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53zkBvL4ZB4

Comment: I don't see onClick method anywhere